# Does RSA encrypt each character in a message separately?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm working on a homework assignment on paper where I must design an RSA cryptosystem and show the steps of encrypting/decrypting a message by hand.

I have selected and calculated my `p`, `q`, `n`, and `phi(n)`. I am now encrypting the message `"HELLO"`. I have started by breaking each letter into its ASCII equivalent such that `H = 72`, `E = 69`, and so forth.

My question is should I encrypt/decrypt each letter separately to/from ciphertext or is there a better way to do it while leaving it as one string?

It seems daunting to have to do the Extended Euclidean Algorithm by hand for all the letters in order to find the decryption key.

I ask this question because I assume that RSA handles this in a better way as to not have to run encryption on each character but encrypt it as a whole.

TL;DR Should I encrypt each letter separately or can I do it all at once?

Comment: The encryption and decryption keys are only calculated once,  For each character (or larger block), all you're doing is the modular exponentiation using the exponent and modulus already chosen.

Comment: Okay so If I have the string message = HELLO and I want to encrypt using Ciphertext = message^e (mod N) where e = 5 and n = 77 how would I break up the different characters? Should I apply this encryption sequentially to each character or can I lump them together somehow?

Comment: Your modulus is too small to lump multiple characters together. Even if you want to use it for encrypting individual characters, you need an encoding step, because you cannot assume ASCII encoding (some characters are larger than 76).

Comment: Possibly map your alphabet to values 0 .. 25 by e.g. subtracting the ASCII value of `A` from each ASCII encoded character. Then encrypt the resulting number. You can store the ciphertext as numbers separated by spaces. Yes, this has a lot of overhead but 1. even RSA with large numbers has a lot of overhead and 2. this is only a learning assignment in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

RSA encrypts the whole message by converting the whole text into a very large integer usually by putting an integer representation of each character in the text side by side and then applying the public key. If each character is encrypted separately, the encrypted message will be vulnerable to [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis).